# Ipyleaflet map object doesn't display in Jupyter Notebook but it gets created

Tags: leaflet, tiles, python-3, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When running the code from the example (https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/map.html#example), no map get displayed.

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles

m = Map(
    layers=(basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.NASAGIBS.ModisTerraTrueColorCR, "2017-04-08"), ),
    center=(52.204793, 360.121558),
    zoom=4
)

m
```

No error message pops up.
The map object gets created:

```
type(m)
>>> ipyleaflet.leaflet.Map
```

It just doesn't get rendered.
Any hints?

After a while, this message appears :
"A Jupyter widget could not
be displayed because the widget state could not be found. This could
happen if the kernel storing the widget is no longer available, or if
the widget state was not saved in the notebook. You may be able to
create the widget by running the appropriate cells."

It suggests that something with the widget is not working, but I can't understand what.

Versions:
ipyleaflet: 0.9.1
ipywidgets: 7.4.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried to install `ipyleaflet` with Jupyter 5.2.3:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipyleaflet
```

and also didn't get a map. I then tried registering the extension with:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
```

since this is mentioned after the *install with pip* section.

After restarting the kernel, the map was now displayed.

Is `jupyter_client` in your old environment <5.3, and >=5.3 in the new clean one?

Comment: I have `jupyter_client 5.2.3 py36_0` in my old environment and `jupyter_client 5.2.4 py_0` in the new one. Is this the issue?

Comment: It could explain why it didn't work in the old environment, but it doesn't explain why it does in the new one.

Comment: It worked. I just run `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet` in conda in my old env. Now I am able to display maps directly in my old env. Thanks a lot MarcPfister

Answer (score 0):

I created a whole new virtual environment with anaconda, and installed only the basic packages (with their relative dependencies) to run ipyleaflet.

1. ipyleaflet 0.9.1
2. nb_conda (for creating a jupyter notebook with the purposely clean environment

Now it all works smoothly.
A nice workaround will be using Jupyter Lab to run visualisations and maps in a separate kernel working in the new clean environment, and all the analysis in the "old" and cluttered environment.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions didn't work try these two commands in notebook:

```
!jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
!jupyter labextension install jupyter-leaflet
```

source [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/173)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this at your environment.

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    jupyter nbextension install ipyleaflet --user --py
    jupyter nbextension enable ipyleaflet --user --py
```

Similar with the solution for widgetsnbextension posted here:

https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1146

Answer (score 0):

After installing packages, it initially didn't work for me in the Jupyter normal address [Jupyter default adress](http://localhost:8888/notebooks/test_map.ipynb)

But if you first open the http://localhost:8888/lab and then run your file in this medium, it may display the map as it did for mehttp://localhost:8888/lab