# Enabling Jupyter nbextension for ipyleaflet?

Tags: mapping, python-3, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to test out this script https://github.com/tylere/PyDataNYC2017/blob/master/ipynb/satellite_analysis.ipynb but got stuck at the iteractive mapping part.

```
import ipyleaflet
map1 = ipyleaflet.Map(zoom=3, layout={'height':'400px'})
dc = ipyleaflet.DrawControl()
map1.add_control(dc)
map1
```

It produces something like this:

**Map(basemap={'url': 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 'max_zoom': 19, 'attribution': 'Map …**

**ipywidgets** package also produces something similar:

**VBox(children=(Map(basemap={'url': 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 'max_zoom': 19, 'attr…**

Then I tested it using `jupyter nbextension list` but it shows me:

`Known nbextensions:`.

Then I try to fix it according to this post https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/173

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter labextension install jupyter-leaflet
```

However, in Command line it shows me

**Error executing Jupyter command 'labextension': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

I also tried this solution [Ipyleaflet map object doesn't display in Jupyter Notebook but it gets created](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303261/ipyleaflet-map-object-doesnt-display-in-jupyter-notebook-but-it-gets-created)

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
```

shows me error messages:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/bin/jupyter-nbextension", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 988, in start
    super(NBExtensionApp, self).start()
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 255, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 896, in start
    self.toggle_nbextension_python(self.extra_args[0])
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 872, in toggle_nbextension_python
    logger=self.log)
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 483, in enable_nbextension_python
    logger=logger)
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 386, in _set_nbextension_state_python
    for nbext in nbexts]
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 386, in <listcomp>
    for nbext in nbexts]
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 351, in _set_nbextension_state
    cm.update(section, {"load_extensions": {require: state}})
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 136, in update
    self.set(section_name, data)
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 110, in set
    self.ensure_config_dir_exists()
  File "/home/gjiang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 67, in ensure_config_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(self.config_dir, 0o755)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/etc'`

I'm using python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) on jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 18.04

​

​

Answer (score 0):

At least the last command needs to be sudo'd so it should read:

```
sudo jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
```

Comment: Why though, this should be possible to do as normal user without fuxxoring around with system-wide settings.