# Is it possible to use ipyleaflet in a jupyter notebook running on an Anaconda Enterprise server?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

This question is very similar to [Ipyleaflet map object doesn't display in Jupyter Notebook but it gets created](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303261/ipyleaflet-map-object-doesnt-display-in-jupyter-notebook-but-it-gets-created) and uses the same example: https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/map.html#example. In my case, the ipyleaflet Map object displays in a notebook that runs from a local machine, but does not display in a notebook running on an Anaconda Enterprise server. I created an environment yml file on the server and activated it via `anaconda-project prepare`. To recreate the project locally, I used `conda env export --no-builds > env.yml` (on the server) and `conda env create -f env.yml` (locally). All of the packages are installed with conda which automatically enables the ipyleaflet extension in the notebook.